# flutter stream shows error type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter, I need to read data from api and store in a list, but I get the error type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String', please help me

```
class HomeController extends ControllerMVC {
List<Slide> slides = <Slide>[];
HomeController() {
  listenForSlides();
}
Future<void> listenForSlides() async {
  final Stream<Slide> stream = await getSlides();
  stream.listen((Slide _slide) {
    setState(() => slides.add(_slide));
  }, onError: (a) {
    print(a);
  }, onDone: () {});
}


Future<void> refreshHome() async {
  setState(() {
    slides = <Slide>[];
  });
  await listenForSlides();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `onError` is an object not a string, if you want to print out the whole error stack object add a `.toString()`:

```
 onError: (a, stackTrace) {
    print(a.toString());
  }, onDone: () {});
```

Comment: it is print the same message type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String'!!!

Comment: ok found it, the error was in the Slide model, I should set it to .toString print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e.toString()));